# Modeling drunkeness over time

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

So you have the function of drunkenness,$D(t)$, the amount of alcohol in your blood, for $t>0$, over time,$t$ in hours:

$$D(t)=T-ct$$

$c$ being the arbitrary amount of alcohol your liver will process in 1 hour.  $T$ being the total amount of alcohol you have drunk at time t.

So T does depend on t, but it still a totally arbitrary amount.

As a piece wise function based on $T=c_nt$. $c_n=nc$ with n being some non negative number, representing the number of drinks of strength c had in 1 hours time:

$$T= \begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      t=1 & n_1c \\
      t=2 & n_2c \\
      ... \\
      t=n & n_nc
    \end{array}
\end{array}$$

So to find T for a certain time, t,

$$T(t=n)=n_1c+n_2c...+...n_nc=(n_1+n_2+n_n)c$$

The number of drinks had each hour is totally arbitrary.  Now what I want to do is to compare this between different values of c.  Like comparing the same amount of drinking between a light beer (call it 1c) and a craft beer (2c). Is there a way to generalize this.

For example:

$$T= \begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      t=1 & 2c \\
      t=2 & 1c \\
      t=3 & 3c
    \end{array}
\end{array}$$

$$T(t=3)=6c$$

So

$$D(t=3)=3c$$

but if c=2c

$$T(t=3)=12c$$

and

$$D(t=3)=9c$$

So drunkenness is not a linear relationship related to the strength of alcohol you are drinking.

Comment: I am maybe not drunk enough to understand your question.

Comment: Is there a way to compare drunkenness for any arbitrary rate of drinking between different strength drinks?

Comment: As a side note, I think blood alcohol concentration is usually modelled by exponential decay rather than the constant rate of decrease you are using, since the rate that the liver processes it is proportional to the concentration.

Answer (score 2):

Using this rather oversimplified model, the drunkenness function $$D(T,t)=T-ct$$
is indeed not linear in $T$.  We have $$\frac{D(mT,t)}{D(T,t)}=\frac{mT-ct}{T-ct}$$
which will only equal $m$ at $t=0$.

The part about piecewise definition for $T$ is totally unnecessary.  $T=T(t)$ is just the sum of all the alcohol drunk by time $t$.

For the record, using both $T$ and $t$ in the same math problem is a clear warning sign of drunkenness.